# Facebook SDK for .NET - not working

Tags: asp.net

I need a Facebook login button for an ASP.NET 4.5 site (not MVC).

I have followed this tutorial for the Facebook SDK:
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/

But it skips over several points, doesn't provide any downloads and just doesn't work.

How can I do this - ideally using built in methods that require little work to implement - and allow you to retrieve email from Facebook. If that isn't possible a NuGet package (ideally one that is widely used) would be fine.

The Facebook SDK for .NET looks promising but I can't get it working and can't find other examples of its use online.

UPDATE

I need the user to press login, be authenticated, then give me their email (from fb?), enter a password.

I need to know all this and manipulate it all from C# code behind.

If they are already logged into FB - and already signed up for my site - I need them to be auto logged in (I will be using custom authentication on the asp.net side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I followed this tutorial: 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-FaceBook-account-in-ASPNet-Website.aspx

This was excellent and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the Facebook login or singup button then you do not need Facebook **.Net SDK**. You need to use Facebook **Javascript SDK**. Then you can use the `<fb:login-button>` XFBML tag.
If the user is already logged in to Facebook, the plugin can show the user's profile picture, if configured to.
Please refer here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Comment: thanks. I need the user to press login, be authenticated, then give me their email (from fb?), enter a password, then know it worked. (I have clarified in question)

Comment: Do you want to get the email of the user? If the user is already logged in to facebook, then?

Comment: yeah Ive seen this on a few sites. 'sign up with facebook' then you're asked for email (maybe auto-filled) along with a password for the site. The MVC Facebook stuff does this.

Comment: thanks. Can it allow them to login to an asp.net web app using the above method? How can I authenticate them in .net? ie how do I get their details into the C# back end, how does c# know they've been authenticated?

Comment: to clarify further. I need signup and login. If they are signing up (login for first time) they're asked for email & password. Otherwise they're auto-logged in if they're already logged in on fb.

Comment: So that was what my previous answer was all about. But to get them to log in to your app, or Facebook, or to ask for email specific permission and allow your app, you have to use javasript. Then when you get the access token and permission from the user, you can use C# to get his/her email ID.

Comment: ok - is there a sample solution or page that explains this in detail for asp.net - with an end to end solution? The fb page only really references javascript.